# How to set up my database with a Question/Answer app Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to the Firestore database so bear with me.

I am building a question/answer app with Flutter and Firestore. The questions are asked by us (backend) and is answered by a user with all answers public (All users seeing all answers). How would be the best way to set this up in the Firestore database?

Answer (score 2):

For you to connect your Flutter application with Firebase, I would recommend you take a look at the following articles and tutorials, on how to achieve this integration.

- [Add Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)
- [Integrate Flutter project with Firebase](https://medium.com/@azpm95/integrate-flutter-project-with-firebase-efb687dd5e8)

Once you achieve, you should be fine with the use of Firebase as a database for your application. After that, I found some repositories and articles that might give you some insights on question/answer application, in different formats, either quiz or forums, that I hope you will help you.

**Repositories:**

- [firebase-android-quiz-app](https://github.com/iamgroot2/firebase-android-quiz-app)
- [Online Quiz App using Firebase](https://github.com/Suhanshu123/Kv-z)

**Articles:**

- [Flutter: how to build a quiz game](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-how-to-build-a-quiz-game-596d0f369575)
- [Answering Questions on Flutter App Development](https://medium.com/@dev.n/answering-questions-on-flutter-app-development-6d50eb7223f3)

Let me know if the information helped you.